# unable to display the main content page

Tags: php, html

In the below code I am trying to display a header, side navigation bar and main content part in page. But it does not display anything. It gives an error of parse error :unexpected end of file. What could be the problem?

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Hello</title>
 </head>

 <body style="background-color:#eee">
   //**Container**
  <div id = "container-userloginview">

 //**header**
<div id = "header-userloginview">
        <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
    //**Content**
   <div id = "content-userloginview">

      //**side navigation bar**
     <div id= "nav-userloginview">
         <h3>Locations</h3>
         <h3>Appointment</h3>
         <h3>Consultation Fee</h3>
     </div>

      //**main content**
     <div id = "main-userloginview">
       <?php
      include_once("connection.php");
      include("username_display.php");  
      $sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME,QUALIFICATION,Specialization from    
           t_doctorprofile";
       $results = mysqli_query($db,$sql)
       or die('Error in connection');


      echo '<h3>Available Dr</h3>';

     while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
  echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 
  10px;';
   echo "<p>".$result['FIRST_NAME']."</p>";
   echo "<p>".$result['QUALIFICATION']."</p>";
   echo "<p>".$result['Specialization']."</p>";
   echo '</div>';
  ?>
   }
   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in closing of while loop

```
?>
}
```

It should be

```
    } //    <--- close before the close of ?> tag
?>
```

your while loop will be

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
  echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 15px; margin-bottom:10px;';
  echo "<p>".$result['FIRST_NAME']."</p>";
  echo "<p>".$result['QUALIFICATION']."</p>";
  echo "<p>".$result['Specialization']."</p>";
  echo '</div>';
}   //   --- this line
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `?>` in the right place: it should be **after the closing brace**:

```
while (something) {
   //code
}
?>
```

What's more, I don't think you can use comments like this in HTML (note that everything that isn't inside `<?php ?>` is plain HTML), you should use `<!-- comment -->`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
?>
   }
```

Basically, you are trying to execute php code outside of php program. It should be:

```
}
?>
```